# Error while implementing Room

Tags: android, mvvm, android-room

error:

```
Entities and Pojos must have a usable public constructor. You can have an empty constructor or a constructor whose parameters match the fields (by name and type).
```

My entity is

```
@Entity
data class Category(var category: String) {

@field: PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
var categoryId: Int = 0


}
```

Comment: post your model class for reference.

Comment: The error explains what is wrong. Add an empty constructor (for example: `public Dog(){}`)

Answer (score 0):

As per error message, you need to add constructer for this class.

```
@Entity data class Category(var category: String) {

@field: PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) var categoryId: Int = 0

constructor() : this(0) 

}
```